# Magento Address Templates Region Code

Tags: magento

I'm creating a website in Magento (v.1.9.2.4) and I want to format the addresses using only the region code instead of the whole region name (Ex: Rhode Island to RI)

I know the template is located on `Customer Configuration > Address Templates`

> {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend company}}{{var company}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
> {{/if}}
>   {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
>   {{var country}}
>   {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend fax}}
> F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend vat_id}}
> VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}`

But when I change `{{if region}}{{var region}}` to `{{if regioncode}}{{var regioncode}}` or `{{if region_code}}{{var region_code}}` it does not work.

Does someone can help me with that?
I tried to search for a list of fields as well but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regioncode is not customer address attribute. Only region and region_id are available.

> {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}

will show the full region name like California
We can override the address block in our local folder and customize the code to show the regioncode like CA.

**Change the customer address template:**

> System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration

and scroll down to Address Templates and edit:

> {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}} replace to  {{/if}}{{if
>   region_id}}{{var region_id}}

To override the block copy

> ‘app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php’

into

> ‘app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php’

. Doing only this will let magento read this file from local folder instead of core folder and change `render()` method as below:

```
public function render(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract $address, $format=null)
    {
        switch ($this->getType()->getCode()) {
            case 'html':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML;
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
                break;
            case 'oneline':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE;
                break;
            default:
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                break;
        }

        $formater   = new Varien_Filter_Template();
        $attributes = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getAttributes();

        $data = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
            if (!$attribute->getIsVisible()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'country_id') {
                $data['country'] = $address->getCountryModel()->getName();
            } else if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'region') {
                $data['region'] = Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegion());
            }else if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'region_id') {
```

> $data['region_id'] =
>   Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegionCode());

```
            } else {
                $dataModel = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::factory($attribute, $address);
                $value     = $dataModel->outputValue($dataFormat);
                if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiline') {
                    $values    = $dataModel->outputValue(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ARRAY);
                    // explode lines
                    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                        $key = sprintf('%s%d', $attribute->getAttributeCode(), $k + 1);
                        $data[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $value;
            }
        }

        if ($this->getType()->getHtmlEscape()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }

        $formater->setVariables($data);

        $format = !is_null($format) ? $format : $this->getFormat($address);

        return $formater->filter($format);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for solutions, you can also add a `helper` class to convert the region to region code and call the helper function in your block.

**Example**

Assuming you have already created custom module

*Package/module/Helper/Data.php*

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Helper;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $region
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRegionCode(string $region): array
    {
        $regionCode = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addRegionNameFilter($region)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->toArray();
        return $regionCode;
    }
}
```

**Now need to override your core module**
*Package/module/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" type="Package\Module\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"/>
</config>
```

**And Finally your custom block**
*Package/module/Block/Address/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Package\module\Block\Address\Renderer;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\RendererInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AddressModelInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Format;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\TestFramework\Event\Magento;
use Package\module\Helper\Data;

/**
 * Address format renderer default
 */
class DefaultRenderer extends AbstractBlock implements RendererInterface
{
    /**
     * Format type object
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var ElementFactory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
     */
    protected $_countryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $_addressMetadataService;

    /**
     * @var Mapper
     */
    protected $addressMapper;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param ElementFactory $elementFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface $metadataService
     * @param Mapper $addressMapper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        ElementFactory $elementFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface $metadataService,
        Mapper $addressMapper,
        array $data = [],
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->_addressMetadataService = $metadataService;
        $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve format type object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->_type;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve format type object
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Framework\DataObject $type
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
     */
    public function setType(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $type)
    {
        $this->_type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the format of the address
     *
     * @param AddressModelInterface|null $address
     * @return string
     * All new code should use renderArray based on Metadata service
     */
    public function getFormat(AddressModelInterface $address = null)
    {
        $countryFormat = $address === null
            ? false : $address->getCountryModel()->getFormat(
                $this->getType()->getCode()
            );
        $format = $countryFormat ? $countryFormat->getFormat() : $this->getType()->getDefaultFormat();
        return $format;
    }

    /**
     * Render address
     *
     * @param AddressModelInterface $address
     * @param string|null $format
     * @return mixed
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function render(AddressModelInterface $address, $format = null)
    {
        $address = $address->getDataModel(0, 0);
        return $this->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($address), $format);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getFormatArray($addressAttributes = null)
    {
        $countryFormat = false;
        if ($addressAttributes && isset($addressAttributes['country_id'])) {
            /** @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Country $country */
            $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->load($addressAttributes['country_id']);
            $countryFormat = $country->getFormat($this->getType()->getCode());
        }
        $format = $countryFormat ? $countryFormat->getFormat() : $this->getType()->getDefaultFormat();
        return $format;
    }

    /**
     * Render address by attribute array
     *
     * @param array $addressAttributes
     * @param Format|null $format
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function renderArray($addressAttributes, $format = null)
    {
        switch ($this->getType()->getCode()) {
            case 'html':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML;
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
                break;
            case 'oneline':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE;
                break;
            default:
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                break;
        }

        $attributesMetadata = $this->_addressMetadataService->getAllAttributesMetadata();
        $data = [];
        foreach ($attributesMetadata as $attributeMetadata) {
            if (!$attributeMetadata->isVisible()) {
                continue;
            }
            $attributeCode = $attributeMetadata->getAttributeCode();
            if ($attributeCode == 'country_id' && isset($addressAttributes['country_id'])) {
                $data['country'] = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode(
                    $addressAttributes['country_id']
                )->getName();
            } elseif ($attributeCode == 'region' && isset($addressAttributes['region'])) {
                $data['region'] = (string)__($addressAttributes['region']);
                $regionName = $addressAttributes['region'];
                $regionData= $this->helper->getRegionCode($regionName);
                $regionArray = $regionData;
                $data['region_code'] = $regionArray['code'];

            } elseif (isset($addressAttributes[$attributeCode])) {
                $value = $addressAttributes[$attributeCode];
                $dataModel = $this->_elementFactory->create($attributeMetadata, $value, 'customer_address');
                $value = $dataModel->outputValue($dataFormat);
                if ($attributeMetadata->getFrontendInput() == 'multiline') {
                    $values = $dataModel->outputValue(ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ARRAY);
                    // explode lines
                    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                        $key = sprintf('%s%d', $attributeCode, $k + 1);
                        $data[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $data[$attributeCode] = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($this->getType()->getEscapeHtml()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }
        $format = $format !== null ? $format : $this->getFormatArray($addressAttributes);
        return $this->filterManager->template($format, ['variables' => $data]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add an example of how to do it. The accepted answer describes it very well. Your answer should add new things to the actual accepted answer.

Comment: I have added the example code please check it.